# Read calender view of a contact in outlook365 API

Tags: office365, office365-restapi, office365connectors

I can able to read my calendar view like below:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime=2017-03-20T01:00:00&endDateTime=2017-3-20T23:00:00&$select=Subject,Organizer,Start,End
```

by passing accesstoken in request header.

I could not able to find a way in documentation to get calendar View for different contact in organisation by passing there email/Id. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for this myself.

Below is the API call which get's calendar for a contact.

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/@emailAdderess/calendarview?startDateTime=2017-03-23T01:00:00&endDateTime=2017-3-23T23:00:00
```